# Ansible: the local .ansible folder is created with root as it's owner (permission errors)

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, ansible

I installed ansible from its [installation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#installation-guide) guide for Ubuntu 14.04, but it creates a .ansible folder in the home directory of my user and when I would like to run a simple test command I get this error:

```
[ERROR]: Unable to set correct type for configuration entry for DEFAULT_LOCAL_TMP: Unable to
create local directories(/home/myuser/.ansible/tmp): [Errno 13] Permission denied:
'/home/myuser/.ansible/tmp'
```

ERROR! Invalid configuration settings

How I can fix this?

Comment: Is your /home/user is on NFS with special settings(Such as root squash)? Answer from @Bryan Calvo Benoit will work .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you executed the command using root or sudo, would be great if you show the permissions of the .ansible folder.

As a workaround I suggest you to explicitly indicate another path for the tmp folder something like '/tmp'. You can achieve this by adding below line to your ansible.cfg:

```
remote_tmp     = /tmp/.ansible/tmp
```

Remember to create the /tmp/.ansible/tmp using the same user that will execute ansible.